# Receiving Negative Input Dimensions with TensorFlow MonitoredTrainingSession

Tags: tensorflow

I'm attempting to switch from a `tf.Session()` to a `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` (all on one machine, no fancy distributed computing), but I'm getting an error that I don't fully understand.

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1148] Invalid argument: Shape [16,-1,4] has negative dimensions
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:644] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Shape [16,-1,4] has negative dimensions
 [[Node: define_inputs/Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[16,?,4], _device="/job:local/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Further down, I receive a little more information about the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1139, in _do_call
  return fn(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1121, in _run_fn
  status, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 89, in __exit__
  next(self.gen)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
  pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
```

I'm using `tf.contrib.seq2seq` and my input and output sequences have variable lengths e.g. `x_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, None, 4])`.

I suspect that the queues that I'm using to read data and bucket data by sequence length are somehow failing or getting interrupted by the `MonitoredTrainingSession`, as I don't have this problem with a vanilla `Session`.

Here's the code that sets up the `MonitoredTrainingSession`

```
# create a global step
global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()

# define graph
model = import_model(global_step)

# create a one process cluster with an in-process server
server = tf.train.Server.create_local_server()

# define hooks for writing summaries and model variables to disk
hooks = construct_training_hooks(model.summary_op)

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,
                                       is_chief=True,
                                       hooks=hooks) as monitored_sess:

    # create coordinator to handle threading
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

    # start threads to enqueue input minibatches for training
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=monitored_sess, coord=coord)

    # train
    while not monitored_sess.should_stop():
        train_op(monitored_sess, model, x_train, y_train, y_lengths_train)

    # when done, ask the threads to stop
    coord.request_stop()

    # wait for threads to finish
    coord.join(threads)
```

Here is how I'm creating my training hooks:

```
def construct_training_hooks(summary_op):

    hooks = [tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=tf.flags.FLAGS.training_steps),
             tf.train.CheckpointSaverHook(checkpoint_dir=tf.flags.FLAGS.log_dir,
                                          saver=tf.train.Saver(),
                                          save_steps=10),
             tf.train.SummarySaverHook(output_dir=tf.flags.FLAGS.log_dir,
                                       summary_op=summary_op,
                                       save_steps=10)]

    return hooks
```

Comment: Where is x_placeholder fed in your code? It's hard to see in the example.

Comment: I removed the placeholders, as converting tensors to Numpy arrays and then using feed_dicts was slowing my code down. Now I just pipe the tensors produced by the queues directly into my encoder for my sequence to sequence model.

Comment: So I assume you don't get the error anymore, as that error is about placeholders?

Comment: Correct, although now I have to figure out how to alternate training data and validation data without using placeholders